# How to group_by in R dplyr specific way?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame with three columns FROM, TO (direction from, direction to) and COUNT:

```
FROM, TO, COUNT
A, B, 3
B, A, 4
C, D, 1
X, Y, 6
D, C, 9
```

I need to group by rows and sum the COUNT, if I have a opposite direction present in the data.frame.

**Expected result**:

```
FROM, TO, COUNT
A, B, 7  <------- (A, B) 3 + 4 (B,A)
C, D, 10 <- (C, D) 1 + 9 (D,C)
X, Y, 6  <- stays as there is no opposite Y to X
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `pmin` and `pmax` to consider the groups in different order as the same and then `sum` each group.

In `dplyr` you can do this as -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(col1 = pmin(FROM, TO), col2 = pmax(FROM, TO)) %>%
  summarise(COUNT = sum(COUNT)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Or in base R -

```
aggregate(COUNT~FROM + TO, 
           transform(df, FROM = pmin(FROM, TO), TO = pmax(FROM, TO)), sum)

#  FROM TO COUNT
#1    A  B     7
#2    C  D    10
#3    X  Y     6
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(COUNT = sum(COUNT)), .(col1 = pmin(FROM, TO), col2 = pmax(FROM, to))]
```